# CMake kits .... are they just for VS Code or would I use them for other environments too?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, cmake, embedded

Background:   I work in a company with many preferences.   We currently use makefiles for our complex build with the developer's choice of IDE (or even VIM) for editing source files.

I'm looking at CMake to clean up our un-tame-able gnu make build system.  I like the integration with VS Code, but I couldn't possibly manage to dictate the IDE to many of our more prickly DSP engineers and their preferred editing environment (which I totally understand; I'm a bit of Visual Studio guy, myself).

Anyways, is the cmake-kits.json method of specifying kits or toolchains/targets/etc. the "right" way to do it?  Or is that just for VS Code.

If it's just for VS Code, what's the proper CMake-y way to put in new toolchains (we do cross compiling using non-gnu tools for 3 different processors) that would work in VSCode, or eclipse, or from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kits are part of the CMake extension for VS Code.  You want to read [cmake-toolchains(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). A kit is something like setting `CC` and `CXX` in the environment so CMake knows which compiler to use for Makefile and Ninja generators. It is different for the other generators as the IDE can control which exact compiler is used and you tell CMake which toolset to use and it generates the project accordingly. FYI, kits don't handle having to write your own toolchain file for cross compilers.

You can use a toolchain file for cross compiling.  This can be simple to hard depending on the compiler and how well it acts like a `gcc` cross compiler.  If it's really different a toolchain file isn't quite enough as you then need to update the platform items to get it all working.  Since this gets into the area of being CMake implementation dependent it's not that well documented.  But there is help at https://discourse.cmake.org/.

You could just use Ninja as the build tool.  Then you setup your toolchain file. After your original run on CMake to create the Ninja project files, you can just run Ninja to build the software.

Then it's easy to set your IDE to just call Ninja to build the software.

Personally, I don't like the CMake integration in VS Code (it's just an add-on). It's always been too buggy for me to want to use it.  But it was good for pulling the information out of the build to get the cpp-tools setup correctly. As for project files for `Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja` I've never personally used them.